# mktime() seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mktime

I am trying to add a week repeatedly to an event struct, which contains date information. I am doing this in order to create a multiple instances of an event up until a certain time. I'm getting a seg fault on my mktime function where full_time = mktime(&caltime); and I have no clue why.

```
void multiple(icalevent event, int is_location){
    icalevent temp;
    int rrule_bound = atoi(event.rrule);
    int rtime_bound = atoi(event.rtime);
    int start_bound = atoi(event.start);
    int stime_bound = atoi(event.stime);
    char buffer[9];
    struct tm caltime;
    time_t full_time;
    char time_str[15];

    temp = cpystruct(event, is_location); 
    while((start_bound <= rrule_bound) && (stime_bound <= rtime_bound)){
        memset(&caltime, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
        strncpy(time_str, temp.start, 9);
        strncat(time_str, temp.stime, 6);

        strptime(time_str, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", &caltime);
        caltime.tm_mday += 7;
        full_time = mktime(&caltime);
        if(caltime.tm_isdst == 1){
            caltime.tm_hour -= 1;
        }
        full_time = mktime(&caltime);

        strftime(buffer, 9, "%Y%m%d", &caltime);
        start_bound = atoi(buffer);
        strncpy(temp.end, buffer, 8);
        strncpy(temp.start, buffer, 8);

        if((start_bound <= rrule_bound) && (stime_bound <= rtime_bound)){
            /*create a sort string*/

            calendar[percent_full] = cpystruct(temp, is_location);
            printst(calendar[percent_full]);
            percent_full++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }

    }

    return;
    }
```

The `icalevent` structure:

```
    typedef struct{
        char start[9]; /*"YYYYMMDD*/
        char stime[7]; /*"HHMMSS"*/
        char end[9]; /*"YYYYMMDD"*/
        char etime[7]; /*"HHMMSS"*/
        char rrule[9]; /*"YYYYMMDD"*/
        char rtime[7]; /*"HHMMSS"*/
        char *location; /*"2343 fake street"*/
        char *summary; /*"Halloween party"*/
        char *sort_str; /*"YYYYMMDDHHMMSSHalloween party*/
     } icalevent
```

*Edit*:

```
icalevent cpystruct(icalevent temp, int is_location) {
    icalevent perm;
    strncpy(perm.start, temp.start, 9);
    strncpy(perm.stime, temp.stime, 7);
    strncpy(perm.end, temp.end, 9);
    strncpy(perm.etime, temp.etime, 7);
    strncpy(perm.rrule, temp.rrule, 9);
    strncpy(perm.rtime, temp.rtime, 7);
    if(is_location) {
        perm.location = strdup(temp.location);
    } else {
        perm.location = NULL;
    }

    perm.summary = strdup(temp.summary);
    perm.sort_str = strdup(temp.sort_str);
    return perm;
}
```

Comment: How is `cpystruct` defined?

Comment: `icalevent cpystruct(icalevent temp, int is_location){

    icalevent perm;

    strncpy(perm.start, temp.start, 9);
    strncpy(perm.stime, temp.stime, 7);
    strncpy(perm.end, temp.end, 9);
    strncpy(perm.etime, temp.etime, 7);
    strncpy(perm.rrule, temp.rrule, 9);
    strncpy(perm.rtime, temp.rtime, 7);

    if(is_location){
        perm.location = strdup(temp.location); 
    }else{
        perm.location = NULL;
    }
    perm.summary = strdup(temp.summary);
    perm.sort_str = strdup(temp.sort_str);

    return perm;
}`

Comment: I added `cpystruct` to your question. It's easier to read there. You can easily do that yourself. Just use the small "edit" link below the question.

Comment: You could improve the reliability of the `cpystruct` code by using `sizeof(temp.start)` instead of `9`, etc. You could also use `memmove()` or `memcpy()` instead of `strncpy()`. But it isn't obvious that there's a problem in that function.  You don't check the return value from `strptime()`; if that fails, you've got a seriously misinitialized variable that you're passing to `mktime()`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your problem is not `mktime`, but one of your copy statements.
First one is

```
strncat(time_str, temp.stime, 6);
```

with this `time_str` is likely not NUL terminated.

Same here

```
strncpy(temp.end, buffer, 8);
strncpy(temp.start, buffer, 8);
```

`temp.end` and `temp.start` might be NUL terminated, when they were before, but you can't be sure. Just use `strcpy` instead.

Next one is

```
calendar[percent_full] = cpystruct(temp, is_location);
printst(calendar[percent_full]);
percent_full++;
```

I see no check for the end of `calendar`. So there might be a write beyond the end of calendar.

As an aside, when you do

```
if(caltime.tm_isdst == 1){
    caltime.tm_hour -= 1;
}
```

`tm_hour` might become negative.

Comment: Okay, I've made the changes to the following strncpys and strncats. I made sure to check to calendar and it is fine because once it is totally full memory is reallocated with realloc(). If tm_hour becomes negative and we call mktime() again, won't it reset the hours back to the proper format?

Comment: strcpy(time_str, temp.start);
        strcat(time_str, temp.stime);

        strptime(time_str, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", &caltime);
        caltime.tm_mday += 7;
        full_time = mktime(&caltime);
        if(caltime.tm_isdst == 1){
            caltime.tm_hour -= 1;
        }
        full_time = mktime(&caltime);

        strftime(buffer, 9, "%Y%m%d", &caltime);
        strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y%m%d", &caltime);
        strncpy(temp.start, buffer,8);
        temp.start[8] = '\0';
        strncpy(temp.end, buffer, 8);
        temp.end[8] = '\0';

Comment: @user1871057 You're right about mktime. According to [mktime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime), it normalizes struct tm fields.

Comment: ohh okay, do you have any other suggestions for why there would be a seg fault. When I run the debugger it throws a seg fault error on the same line with the mktime function.

Comment: @user1871057 Besides the suggestions I've given, not really. Depending on how cpystruct is defined, there could be a problem as well. But that is just guesswork.

Comment: `tm_hour` going negative should not be a problem; `mktime()` is intended to normalize the input data.  That's why adding a week works.